# Closed orbit for vector field $f(\bar{z})$ where $f$ is holomorphic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

**Edit :** According to the  comments of  Michael Renardy and  Christian  Remling  I revise the question as follows:

Is  there  a  vector  field  $X$  on  an open set  $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$  such that $X $ has  a  closed orbit and is  in the  form  $X=f(\bar{z})$ where $f$  is  a  holomorphic  function on $\overline{U}=\{\bar{z}\mid z\in U\}$?

**Added  after the answer  by  Prof.  Duchon:** Is there  an  example  of such  vector field with an  Isochronous  band  of closed orbits?

Comment: Wouldn't such a vector field be divergence free?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy  Yes  of  course. Thank  you  for  your very  interesting point. My apology  for  my  elementary question.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy  Is there an example of such vector field with a  band of closed orbits on for a   (non  simply  connected ) open set $U$ ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling  Yes, Thank you.  I understand you are saying that  two  vector  fields  $f(\bar{z})$  and  $\overline{f(z)}$  are  smoothly equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $U=\{z:a<|z|<b\}$ ($a>0$) and $f(z)=i/\bar z$. Orbits are circles $\{|z|=c\}$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Duchon. Thank you  so much  for  this  answer. Is  there  an example  of  such  vector  field  with  a  band  of  closed orbits with  constant  period?

Comment: May  I  have your  email address? My I ask you that  you  kindly send  me a message to my  email address   "alitghv@yahoo.com"?Thank you.